# ViewController/View's size not updating accordingly to navigationbar and tabbar

Tags: ios, xcode

I needed some help please, from the image, I have a BlueViewController embedded in a UINavigationController then set them as one of the view controllers stack in a UITabBarController.

I'm wondering why the BlueViewController's view size is not changed accordingly. Or I'm missing some important information because my other project works perfectly.

The BlueViewController's view's autoresizingMask is set to flexibleHeight and width. This is written without storyboard in Swift 4.2, XCode 10.1.

[image]

Comment: Why haven’t you posted the code?

Comment: @Magnas I've found the problem and posted an answer below. Just a simple mistake by don't understand how view controllers works :(

Answer (score 2):

Just found the answer, for anyone who is curious.

UIViewController's edgesForExtendedLayout is the one doing the job, setting it to all means that your view inside ur controller extends/ignore the navbar and tabbar. If I'm even partially wrong please correct me ty.